# Uploading to FTP from WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, file-upload, ftp

I once made a WinForms FTP uploader, and it worked very good.
now, I'm trying to make the same program, just with a new look and in WPF a very organized one too.

I tried using a `WebClient` and `UploadFileAsync` [so it won't block the calling thread], as I did with the WinForms, but in the WPF, instead of uploading the file, absolutely nothing happened. the program just kept running as if nothing happened.
so I tried to use the method `UploadFile` [that does block the calling thread] and than the window just freezed forever. so now I tried to use `FTPWebRequest` and the same, the program just freezes.

Is there a special way for WPF to upload files? or can it even upload at all?
because I'm sure my code is fine.
Thanks.

Edit:
this is the code for the UploadFileAsync:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
        client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("ftp://server.com/"), "STOR", "C:\\file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls post the example of how you are doing this. WPF is the new GUI framework based on XAML, and everything is based on .NET framework, so all the functionality (that is in your Model) should work as it is.

it could be that you are having proble with actually firing these commands which does the uploading bit.

Comment: Edited the question, it's the method I'd prefer (with having not to block the calling thread of course)

Comment: looking at your code, when using ASync, you usually hook into AsyncResponse or pass some sort of callback which gets called when Async operation is done (in your case, file is being uploaded). Where r u running the above code ? i.e. is it from the ViewModel or Model

Comment: No, I don't I just use this and it's uploading.
I'm running this code in a button click.

Comment: not sure mate, put a breakpoint, not sure why it is not hitting it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient
wc.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("id", "pwd")
wc.UploadFile("ftp://server.com/", filepath)
```